# Map<String, Map<String, Double>> streamapi

Tags: java, java-stream

I can't understand why my code doesn't work. Tell me, if it's not difficult, I really ask.
error in the stream, but I can't figure out why I can't fill Map from List
I want to know what is the student's overall GPA.
the result should be in the form:
key - group
value - student name - score, student name - score

```
class Student4 {

    String name;
    Subject4[] subjects;

    public Student4(String name, Subject4[] subjects) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student4 s1 = new Student4("Name1", new Subject4[]{
                new Subject4("A", new Integer[]{4, 4, 4, 4, 5}), //21 -> 4.2
                new Subject4("B", new Integer[]{5, 5, 5, 5, 5}), //25 -> 5.0
                new Subject4("C", new Integer[]{4, 4, 4, 4, 5})  //21 -> 4.2
        });
        Student4 s2 = new Student4("Name2", new Subject4[]{
                new Subject4("A", new Integer[]{3, 3, 3, 4, 5}), //18 -> 3.6
                new Subject4("B", new Integer[]{5, 3, 3, 5, 5}), //21 -> 4.2
                new Subject4("C", new Integer[]{4, 3, 3, 4, 3})  //17 -> 3.4
        });
        Student4 s3 = new Student4("Name3", new Subject4[]{
                new Subject4("A", new Integer[]{5, 5, 5, 4, 5}), //24 -> 4.8
                new Subject4("B", new Integer[]{5, 5, 5, 4, 5}), //24 -> 4.8
                new Subject4("C", new Integer[]{5, 5, 5, 4, 5})  //24 -> 4.8
        });
        Student4 s4 = new Student4("Name4", new Subject4[]{
                new Subject4("A", new Integer[]{5, 5, 5, 4, 5}), //24 -> 4.8
                new Subject4("B", new Integer[]{5, 5, 5, 4, 5}), //24 -> 4.8
                new Subject4("C", new Integer[]{5, 5, 5, 4, 5})  //24 -> 4.8
        });

        Map<String, List<Student4>> group = new HashMap<>();
        group.put("group1", List.of(s1, s2));
        group.put("group2", List.of(s3, s4));



        Map<String, Map<String, Double>> averageByStudent = group.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(),
                        entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry.getValue().stream()
                                                .map(z -> z.name),
                                        entry.getValue().stream()
                                                .flatMap(v -> Arrays.stream(v.subjects))
                                                .flatMap(w -> Arrays.stream(w.mark))
                                                .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
                                                .average().getAsDouble()
                                ))));
    }
}

class Subject4 {

    String name;
    Integer[] mark;

    public Subject4(String name, Integer[] mark) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mark = mark;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may upvote answers if you feel they were useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in using the [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), this function is expecting two functions as a parameter; one to produce the key and another to produce the value (It doesn't expect a stream of values)

This should work

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

Map<String, Map<String, Double>> averageByStudent = group.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey,
            entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                .collect(toMap(student -> student.name, student ->
                    Arrays.stream(student.subjects)
                        .flatMap(w -> Arrays.stream(w.mark))
                        .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
                        .average().orElse(0d)
                ))));
```

Answer (score 0):

For figuring this out I would follow the following approach:

Use a proper context relative name for your variable names in your lambda, so you can figure out `entry` have different meanings in your first and second collect calls (I renamed them to `entryKeyStringValueListOfStudents`  and `student` to have an idea of what's in there on each situation).

With renaming you'll probably find out the line

```
Collectors.toMap(entry.getValue().stream()
.map(z -> z.name),
```

is meaningless as your currently "streamed" object is a `Student` so there's no need for mapping.

Then changing both you get simpler code:
`student -> student.studentName,` for rendering the key and `student -> Arrays.stream(student.subjects)` for mapping the subjects (there's no need for a flatMap there, you just stream the subjects and map the marks).

After those changes (and some indentation for clarification, not the most beautiful though) you'll finally get:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> averageByStudent = group.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                entryKeyStringValueListOfStudents -> entryKeyStringValueListOfStudents.getKey(),
                entryKeyStringValueListOfStudents -> entryKeyStringValueListOfStudents.getValue()
                        .stream() //stream of students
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    student -> student.studentName,
                                    student -> Arrays.stream(student.subjects) //stream of subjects
                                        .flatMap(subject -> Arrays.stream(subject.mark)) //stream of marks
                                        .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
                                        .average()
                                        .getAsDouble()
                                                 )
                                )
                        )
                );
```

Comment: You may upvote answers if you feel they were useful.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> averageByStudent = group.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(grp -> grp.getKey(), // group1
                grp -> grp.getValue().stream() // s1, s2 etc..
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(student -> student.name,
                                student -> Arrays.stream(student.subjects)
                                .flatMap(subject -> Arrays.stream(subject.mark))
                                .mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).average().getAsDouble()))
        ));
```